# How to exclude some uri to be observed using springboot3/micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer-tracing

Hy

I am using springboot 3 with the new micrometer observation. Is there a way to prevent generating a trace_id/span_id for some paths like /actuator/prometheus? Observation add a trace id for each call to /actuator/*.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a *half* solution to the problem, by defining the `ObservationRegistry` this way:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
ObservationRegistry observationRegistry() {
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher("/");
    ObservationRegistry observationRegistry = ObservationRegistry.create();
    observationRegistry.observationConfig().observationPredicate((name, context) -> {
        if(context instanceof ServerRequestObservationContext) {
            return !pathMatcher.match("/actuator/**", ((ServerRequestObservationContext) context).getCarrier().getRequestURI());
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return observationRegistry;
}
```

This doesn't completely ignore the actuator requests, only the first span. So if you have for example Spring Security on your classpath, those spans are left intact.

EDIT: Looks like you don't need to redefine the entire observation registry, you can use a bean like the one show here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/observability.html

EDIT2: From what I can tell, you need to include these 2 beans, and no actuator call will be traced (completely disables tracing for spring security too):

```java
    @Bean
    ObservationRegistryCustomizer<ObservationRegistry> skipActuatorEndpointsFromObservation() {
        PathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher("/");
        return (registry) -> registry.observationConfig().observationPredicate((name, context) -> {
            if (context instanceof ServerRequestObservationContext observationContext) {
                return !pathMatcher.match("/actuator/**", observationContext.getCarrier().getRequestURI());
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Bean
    ObservationRegistryCustomizer<ObservationRegistry> skipSecuritySpansFromObservation() {
        return (registry) -> registry.observationConfig().observationPredicate((name, context) ->
                !name.startsWith("spring.security"));
    }
```

Also, you might want to keep an eye out on this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29210

Comment: I've seen that is the first span if filtered out (return false by the predicate) the parentOsevation of the subsequent span is a NoopObservation. So when the parent is Noop, I'm also filtering the next spans ...
See response below for full code.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do some filtering with a ObservationPredicate that filters some URLS and filters the next spans too.

I've seen that is the first span if filtered out (return false by the predicate) the parentOsevation of the subsequent span is a NoopObservation.

So when the parent is Noop, I'm also filtering the next spans ...

```
package fr.common.micrometer.observers;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import org.springframework.http.server.observation.ServerRequestObservationContext;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import io.micrometer.observation.Observation.Context;
import io.micrometer.observation.ObservationPredicate;
import io.micrometer.observation.ObservationRegistry;
import io.micrometer.observation.ObservationView;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class UrlObservationPredicate implements ObservationPredicate {

  private static final String REQUEST_NAME = "http.server.requests";

  private static final List<String> DEFAULT_FILTERED_URLS = List.of("/actuator/**");

  private List<AntPathRequestMatcher> filteredUrls;

  public UrlObservationPredicate() {
    this(DEFAULT_FILTERED_URLS);
  }

  public UrlObservationPredicate(List<String> filteredPaths) {
    this.filteredUrls = Optional.ofNullable(filteredPaths)
                                .filter(Predicate.not(Collection::isEmpty))
                                .orElse(DEFAULT_FILTERED_URLS)
                                .stream()
                                .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                                .toList();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test(String name, Context context) {
    if (parentIsNoop(context)) {
      log.trace("Parent is Noop so filtering: {}", name);
      return false;
    }
    if (!REQUEST_NAME.equals(name)) {
      return true;
    }
    if (context instanceof ServerRequestObservationContext requestContext) {
      HttpServletRequest httpRequest = requestContext.getCarrier();
      if (filteredUrls.stream()
                      .anyMatch(matcher -> matcher.matches(httpRequest))) {
        log.trace("Filtering uri: {}", httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private boolean parentIsNoop(Context context) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(context.getParentObservation())
                   .map(ObservationView::getObservationRegistry)
                   .filter(ObservationRegistry::isNoop)
                   .isPresent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information about a problem, but i think you have set this line in application.propeties like:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=/actuator/*
```

But exists option like:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=/actuator/prometheus
```

Comment: hy dr34mer, thank you for the answer. But i need to include the /actuator/prometheus, i use it to monitor the application.

I am using the new observability provided by springboot/micrometer. When prometheus call /actuator/prometheus to scrap metrics, this call will generate a trace/span so i want to prevent generating a traceid/spanid for this path.

Comment: You use zipkin/sleuth I guess. Try with `spring.sleuth.web.skip-pattern=/actuator/prometheus` in your properties. I am not sure is that a correct regex. That should help. [https://github.com](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/SleuthWebProperties.java#L34)

Comment: I am not using sleuth, it's no more supported in spring-boot 3. Spring-boot 3 use micrometer