# How to exclude actuator endpoints from exporting spans from spring boot app 3.2 to jaeger via otlp exporter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jaeger

I am using OtlpHttpSpanExporter to send spans to JAEGER app in my Spring Boot 3.2 application.

All works like a charm but actuators endpoints are also exporting which is quite annoying.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone knows how to skip some urls ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143863/how-to-exclude-some-uri-to-be-observed-using-springboot3-micrometer